# Add static field to grouped data in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

How to add static field to result using group operation in mongodb. My query looks like:

```
db.sales.aggregate({
    $group : {
        _id: {
            year: { $year: '$date' },
        },
        amount: { $sum: 1 }
    }
});
```

Than I get result:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "year" : 2013
            },
            "amount" : 43433
        },
        ...
    ]
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I need to add field called `type` with value `'year'` in each object of the result.

Comment: use [$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) after group.

Answer (score 1):

I just need add project operation with literal 'year'. Query looks like:

```
db.sales.aggregate([
{
    $group : {
        _id: {
            year: { $year: '$registrationDate' }
        },
        amount: { $sum: 1 }
    },
},
{

        $project: {
                type: { $literal: 'year' },

        }    
}

]);
```

Answer (score 0):

$addFields is available in version 3.4+ e.g.

```
db.sales.aggregate({
    $group : {
        _id: {
            year: { $year: '$date' },
        },
        amount: { $sum: 1 }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            type: 'year'
        }
    }
});
```